# SQL Queries (Difference between tables)

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I'm trying to find a difference between two tables. The tables are

***Sample Data***

**PERSON_PHOTO**

```
ID     USERID     FNAME 
801    uid01      Geroge    
801    uid05      George 
803    uid01      George
901    uid01      Alice
201    uid01      Alice
330    uid01      Alice
802    uid05      Alice
803    uid05      Alice
804    uid05      Alice
901    uid05      Alice
701    uid05      Alice
201    uid05      Alice
101    uid05      Alice
330    uid05      Alice
501    uid05      Alice
501    uid12      Jane
330    uid12      Jane
101    uid12      Jane
201    uid12      Jane
701    uid12      Jane
801    uid12      Jane
901    uid12      Jane
101    uid07      Mary
101    uid03      Mary
201    uid03      Mary
801    uid03      Mary
901    uid03      Mary
201    uid15      Tom
801    uid15      Tom
```

**Table VALID_FRIEND**

```
FNAME      USERID
Bill       uid02
George     uid01
Mary       uid07
Jane       uid12
Tom        uid15
Alice      uid05
Mary       uid03
```

**SAMPLE OUTPUT**

```
USERID      PHOTOS NOT IN
uid02       0
uid01       5
uid07       9
uid12       3
uid15       8
uid05       8
uid03       6
```

The query I'm trying to perform is to find the number of Photos that the person is not in. I'm trying to output by USERID and the number of photos not currently in. I know I need to find the count of the distinct PID in person photo and take the difference of the count of the userid in photo. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Well, what have you tried?

Comment: I've been trying to get the two numbers that I need via count. For example
SELECT count (distinct p.userid)
FROM Person_Photo P
WHERE p.userid = 'uid01'

which gives me 5

which gives me 10

Select count(distinct p.pid)
from person_photo p
where userid = 'userid01'

which gives me 5

Comment: Can also provide sample data output of how you want from above posted data

Comment: When is a person not in a photo? Is Mary (uid07) only in photo 101, or is Mary also in 201,801 and 901?

Comment: And Mary has sometimes userid uid03, and sometimes uid07? Clean up the samples, also, no need for both USERID and FNAME in the PERSON_PHOTO table, USERID should do fine alone! (See, now you have Geroge and George for uid01...)